# Displaying information on Jpanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton

I am new to this action command and action listener (mouse pressed) event. i used this in my code:

```
// This is the single event handler for all the buttons
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
JButton selectedBtn = (JButton) e.getSource();

for (int row = 0; row < buttons.length; row++) {
  for (int col = 0; col < buttons[row].length; col++) {
    if (buttons[row][col] == selectedBtn) {
       moves++; //incrementing the moves
       System.out.printf("moves: %d%n", moves);
       System.out.printf("Selected row: %d%n", row+1);
       System.out.printf("Selected column: %d%n", col+1);

     }
   }
 }
```

this piece of code is displaying the rows and columns of the button pressed correctly. but what i'm trying to do is that i'm trying to display this information in front of my Jlabels.

i.e if a button is pressed and it lies on a row 2 and column 4 it should show it like this :

[image]

instead it shows as this in the output console :

```
moves: 1
Selected row: 3
Selected column: 4
```

any ideas on how do I amend these Jlabels so this information displays on them?

these are my Jlabels

```
//labels
JLabel label1 = new JLabel("COL: ");
label1.setLocation(10,260);
label1.setSize(100,100);
add(label1);

JLabel label2 = new JLabel("ROW: ");
label2.setLocation(10,280);
label2.setSize(100,100);
add(label2);
```

any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: Not clear on your exact requirement.If you just need to display those values in the Frame,you can use separate JLabels for the the values and then update those in actionPerformed event,or use non-editable JTextFields for the same.

Comment: [`JLabel#setText`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html), you may also want to take a look at [How to Use Labels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html). Remember, you'll probably need the labels to be class instance fields in order to be able to modify them

Comment: @Arsal Abbas Are you asking how to display text on JLabels?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `setText()` on the instance of JLabel.

Comment: i tried doing something like this :
column.setText((col+1).getText());
since the column is my label name i want to update and the "col+1) is the number of column of the jbutton im getting.
but it keeps giving me an error that "int cannot be dereferenced"

Comment: What is column? What I ment was, you diretly use `label.setText("some text")`. Please refer to the Oracle trail for [Java Swing on JLabel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html).